# "sbt launcher does not exist" when attempting to open sbt project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Here is an attempt to open an `sbt` project in Intellij 2016.3 ultimate:

[image]

We are greeted with the following friendly notification:

[image]

Afa sbt details:  I have installed `sbt` via `homebrew` and

That path truly *does not exist*.  So I went to `Preferences | Build Execution Deployment | SBT` to fix the path:

```
$ll /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.13/libexec/sbt-launch.jar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 boescst  USWIN\Domain Users  1210231 Oct 28 10:46 /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.13/libexec/sbt-launch.jar
```

Let' update the path:

[image]

However the same error message still occurs. Is there some other place in Intellij that needs to be updated?

The following happened when trying to import an sbt project:

[image]

The following dialog has a `Show Logs` link but clicking on it does nothing ..

[image]

**Another update** I opened the `idea.log` manually.  It shows basically same information:

> 2017-01-04 18:07:21,280 [  34384]   WARN -
>   nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - SBT launcher does not exist:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.9/libexec/sbt-launch.jar 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: SBT
>   launcher does not exist:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.9/libexec/sbt-launch.jar   at
>   org.jetbrains.sbt.project.SbtProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(SbtProjectResolver.scala:61)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.sbt.project.SbtProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(SbtProjectResolver.scala:28)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.a(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:414)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:486)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:710)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$11.run(CoreProgressManager.java:423)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:179)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:568)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:519)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:569)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: SBT launcher does not exist:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.9/libexec/sbt-launch.ja

I have ***repeatedly*** tried changing the sbt launch settings. The error still occurs. Intellij is caching that information somewhere. I've even deleted the .idea and .iml files. Same result. Now I have ***reinstalled Intellij***  . Still same issue!  What the heck !!!???

Comment: This is the correct setting, and I can't reproduce your problem with identical settings. However, using the bundled sbt launcher should work fine as well. Is there a reason it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thx for asking:  Using the "bundled" sbt is where I started from - i.e. generating the error message shown. I changed to custom to try to fix the issue -but in both cases same error.

Comment: Can you please link a paste of the IDE log from when the error happens?

Comment: @JustinKaeser  The link provided to the `Show logs` is not working (see the dialog screenshot added to the OP).

Comment: Thanks for the update. No idea what's going on here, but one thing you can try is File / Invalidate chaches and restart. Though that probably won't do much if a reinstallation didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

For Launcher, in preference window, pick "Bundled" option instead of custom.

Comment: Its in Preferences > Build Execution Deployment > Build Tools > sbt

Comment: Using the "bundled" sbt is where I started from - i.e. generating the error message shown. I changed to custom to try to fix the issue -but in both cases same error